# Why isn't $\leq$ definable in $(\mathbb{R};0,+,-)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Are there any simple and straightforward proofs of this fact? I'm not really sure how to begin to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: definable sets are preserved under automorphisms. Can you come up with an automorphism where $a\leq b$ but $f(a)>f(b)$?

Comment: I mean, the only non-trivial automorphism I know for this structure is $h(r)=-r$, and that would seem to do the trick. So I guess what I'm asking why are definable sets preserved under automorphisms?

Comment: You can prove (by induction on the complexity of formulas) that for every automorphism f, that $\phi(\overline{x})$ is true iff $\phi(f(\overline{x}))$ is true.